# neo4j traversal path related to a property on relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, traversal

I have Graph database in Neo4j with Train stations as nodes, and train connecting these stations as directed relationship

for example Train station A is connected to Train station B via relationship train{train no : 123},
train relationship has a property called train no .

My question is getting a path from A to D with all intermediate stations connected with same train number.

A-->B-->C-->D

For this example I should get B, C as returned nodes

I tried

```
MATCH (from:TrainStation { stationCode:'A' }), 
(to:TrainStation {stationCode:'D'}) ,
path = (from)-[r:train*..]->(to)
RETURN path
```

This query gives me path related to all the trains, but I want to restrict it to
specific train number 123

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `ALL` predicate on the relationship property :

```
MATCH (from:TrainStation { stationCode:'A' }), 
(to:TrainStation {stationCode:'D'}) ,
MATCH path = (from)-[r:train*..]->(to)
WHERE ALL (x in rels(path) WHERE x.`train no` = 123)
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thanks Christophe
this works, but takes a lot of time.
I think my graph is not designed well for such queries, as all my queries will be related to a train number
Nevertheless your answer is perfect :) so upvoting

Comment: You're right, the model is not ideal when you need to filter on relationship properties